# get relevant value from useSelector

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have two hooks:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const response = useSelector(state => state.responseData);
```

And `submit` function:

```
        const submit = () => {
        
            dispatch(connectToServer(`${BASE_URL}user/signIn`, {
              email: state.email,
              password: state.password
            }, 'post'))
        
            if (response.data.token) <--- this data is 1 step late
              //do smth
```

I see relevant data only in JSX elements when they are rendered, but there is no way to make a function based on this data, this data is 1 step late.

Answer (score 1):

There's three issues here:

- The `connectToServer` action is presumably doing some async work, so there's no way a response can have been updated by the time the next line runs
- Even if you do `await dispatch(connectToServer())`, React may not have re-rendered yet
- The callback can only reference the variable values that existed in scope *at the time the callback was defined*, ie, the render before the user clicked the "Submit" button.

You'll need to either:

- Move the response handling into the thunk itself
- Have the thunk retrieve the updated data from the store and return it / use it somehow
- Move the response token handling into a `useEffect` and wait for the next re-render that has the right data